# xpath to get non-distinct parent node data for each child node

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, xpath

Google Spreadsheets has an IMPORTXML function, which I am trying to use to maintain a list of TV episodes, based on the API at http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=3183.

I am trying to get a table of `Date | Season No | Episode No | Title` from that XML.

The XML is hierarchical, nesting episodes under seasons.

I can get my date, episode and title columns, using xpath:

- Date - `/Show/Episodelist/Season/episode/airdate`
- Episode No - `/Show/Episodelist/Season/episode/seasonnum`
- Title - `/Show/Episodelist/Season/episode/title`

However, I cannot get seem to find the right xpath to extract the Season number for each episode entry, which is the `no` attribute to the `Season` parent node.

I have tried:

- `/Show/Episodelist/Season/episode/../@no`
- `/Show/Episodelist/Season/episode/parent::Season/@no`

Both of these result in getting a distinct list of seasons, i.e.:

```
Date         Season  Episode  Title
01-01-2001   1       1        foo
02-01-2001   2       2        bar
03-01-2001   3       3        baz
04-01-2001           4        fee
05-01-2001           5        fob
01-03-2002           1        bix
02-03-2002           2        buz
03-03-2002           3        fez
04-03-2002           4        baj
```

...whereas I am looking for:

```
Date         Season  Episode  Title
01-01-2001   1       1        foo
02-01-2001   1       2        bar
03-01-2001   1       3        baz
04-01-2001   1       4        fee
05-01-2001   1       5        fob
01-03-2002   2       1        bix
02-03-2002   2       2        buz
03-03-2002   2       3        fez
04-03-2002   2       4        baj
```

What is the correct xpath so that the IMPORTXML routine does not do a distinct operation on the imported data?

Comment: This is tricky. Your problem seems to be that there is only 1 node that contains the season number, while the other values exists 1 per row. But if you could share an example spreadsheet with us, it would be easier to understand your problem.

Comment: The link return error.

Comment: I think this particular API disappeared around September 2015, and didn't leave a forwarding address. If I find an equivalent XML API, I will update

Comment: From the [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/90377/88163) by @Aurielle, the following URL could work instead of the deprecated API: http://www.tvrage.com/the-layover/episode_list/all

Comment: Yes, but that is scraping the webpage, not reading from a feed. Besides, the feed was an example to demonstrate the problem, not the problem itself - the *problem* was that IMPORTXML only returned unique values, even if the xpath was explicitly crafted to work on non-unique elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, doing this with `=importXML` and XPath seems tricky.

But doing it programmatically, using the [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service) of [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/), looks easier.

I have written the following:

```
function parseTvRageXml(url) {
   var result = [];
   var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
   var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
   var root = document.getRootElement();

   var show = document.getRootElement();
   var episodeList = show.getChild("Episodelist");
   var seasons = episodeList.getChildren("Season");
   for (var i = 0; i < seasons.length; i++) {
     var season = seasons[i];
     var seasonNum = season.getAttribute("no").getValue();
     var episodes = season.getChildren("episode");
     for (var j = 0; j < episodes.length; j++) {
       var episode = episodes[j];
       var resultRow = [];
       resultRow.push(seasonNum);
       resultRow.push(episode.getChild("epnum").getText());
       resultRow.push(episode.getChild("seasonnum").getText());
       resultRow.push(episode.getChild("airdate").getText());
       resultRow.push(episode.getChild("link").getText());
       resultRow.push(episode.getChild("title").getText());
       result.push(resultRow);                
     }
   }
  return result;
 }
```

In effect, it fetches the content from the given URL, parses it as XML, and iterates through the elements, extracting values of the elements you wanted, which is stored in a 2-dimensional array (`result`), and returned.

To use this, you must install the script in your spreadsheet. Click the *Tools* menu → *Script editor*, and paste the code listed above. Save the script.

In the cell where you want the output, enter

```
=parseTvRageXml("http://services.tvrage.com/feeds/episode_list.php?sid=3183")
```

The result should be a list of episodes, with the following columns:

```
Season number | epnum | seasonnum | airdate | link | title
```

I have set up [an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qFryUlGfGT8dp_lx9sSE_7suCV0t8cAg9btM1AOPnSI/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate this, feel free to copy it.

Comment: This is what I have ended up doing, but it is a bit of a pain, because it requires additional permissions (and some too-broad Noscript exclusions).  In any case, it appears to be an issue with XPath, rather than Google Sheets' implementation.

Comment: Not sure I understand what "additional permissions" and "Noscript exclusions" you need. You're installing this in Google Spreadsheets script editor, right? Shouldn't need any specific permissions to run this script - and "Noscript exclusions" shouldn't be part of it, because the script is running server-side.

Comment: Re permissions: Google pops up the 'this app needs access to external data' warning; Re Noscript: all App Scripts are served from googleusercontent.com, so require an additional exclusion.  But these are my constraints, not yours, so don't worry about it :-).

Comment: Oh, OK, I didn't get the "external data" warning. As for Noscript, I still don't think it applies. The script is not _served_ from googleusercontent.com, it is _run_ from Google's servers. As such, the web browser is _not_ part of the equation.

Comment: googleusercontent.com is the domain Google use to serve scripts that they didn't write or validate.  It might be *run* from a Google server, but it isn't 'trusted' Google code.  Like I said, my preference -- you don't have to worry about it.  Thanks!

Comment: I just take the code from this answer as "inspiration" for this other [answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/93150/88163) to [Using Google Spreasheet's IMPORTXML Function to Download Selected Multiple Columns](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/93028/using-google-spreasheets-importxml-function-to-download-selected-multiple-colum)

Answer (score 1):

You now can use importxml and/or importfeed.

This will automatically stack it for you:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.tvrage.com/the-layover/episode_list/all","//h1 |//*[@size='4']| //*[@class='b'][1]/tr | //*[@class='b'][2]/tr")
```

[image]